# How do I use Type.GetMethods inside a static class?

Tags: c#

I have a list of "commands" for a console-line application that I'm developing. One of them is a method that prints all available commands for the player to use. I've tried calling `Type.GetMethods` on the `CommandsList` class in order to list them all, but `returnString` below is empty. After using a breakpoint, I found that `commands` is empty as well, even though public methods exist in `CommandsList`. This is the first time I've tried using `Type.GetMethods`, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. If someone can help me fix this, I would appreciate it. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class CommandsList {
    //(Other commands)
    public static void Commands() {
        MethodInfo[] commands = typeof(CommandsList).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
        string returnString = "";
        foreach(MethodInfo info in commands) {
            returnString += info.Name + " ";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(returnString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the command you want static methods:

```
var commands = typeof(CommandsList).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```